# Error DataSource.Factory must be provided when Unit Testing RawQuery

Tags: unit-testing, android-room

I'am trying to do testing for rawquery using Room. I am using JUnit 4. Here is my code:

```
// MovieRepositoryTest.kt        
@Test
fun getWatchlistTv() {
    val query = getSortedTv(DEFAULT)
    val dataSourceFactory = mock(DataSource.Factory::class.java) as DataSource.Factory<Int, TvEntity>
    val dummy = DummyData.generateTvWatchlist(tvResponse)
    `when`(local.getWatchlistTv(query)).thenReturn(dataSourceFactory)
    movieRepository.getWatchlistTv(DEFAULT) // here is the line 90

    val tvEntities = PagedListUtil.mockPagedList(dummy)

    verify(local).getWatchlistTv(query)
    assertNotNull(tvEntities)
    assertEquals(tvWatchlist.size, tvEntities.size)
}

// Dao
@RawQuery(observedEntities = [TvEntity::class])
fun getWatchlistTv(query: SupportSQLiteQuery): DataSource.Factory<Int, TvEntity>
```

And this is the code in repository:

```
override fun getWatchlistTv(sort: String): LiveData<PagedList<TvEntity>> {
    val query = getSortedTv(sort)
    return LivePagedListBuilder(localDataSource.getWatchlistTv(query), config).build() // line 94 error
}
```

And the error is:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DataSource.Factory must be provided

    at androidx.paging.LivePagedListBuilder.<init>(LivePagedListBuilder.java:63)
    at com.wiryadev.bajpmovie.data.FakeMovieRepository.getWatchlistTv(FakeMovieRepository.kt:94)
    at com.wiryadev.bajpmovie.data.MovieRepositoryTest.getWatchlistTv(MovieRepositoryTest.kt:90)
```

**Attempted Solution**

- Using `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)` for the class
- Using `@Mock private lateinit var dataSourceMovieWatchList: DataSource.Factory<Int, MovieEntity>` instead of mock(class)

The datasource mock is not null when i do not use RawQuery. Then, i think it is because RawQuery have different way to do this. So how to solve this? Any help is appreciated.

Additional Info: in case anyone need to know code i use (and works) for non-rawquery function:

```
// Reposiory Test
@Test
fun discoverTv() {
    val dataSourceFactory = mock(DataSource.Factory::class.java) as DataSource.Factory<Int, TvEntity>
    `when`(local.discoverTv()).thenReturn(dataSourceFactory)
    movieRepository.discoverTv()

    val tvEntities = Resource.success(PagedListUtil.mockPagedList(DummyData.generateSeries()))

    verify(local).discoverTv()
    assertNotNull(tvEntities.data)
    assertEquals(tvResponse.size, tvEntities.data?.size)
}

// Dao
@Query("SELECT * FROM tv_entities")
fun discoverTv(): DataSource.Factory<Int, TvEntity>
```